# Bluebird promise on array of functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have an array of functions that need to be read from a JSON file:
`"functionArray" : ["task1()", "task2()", ... , "taskN()"]`

My requirement is to call these tasks sequentially so that task2 function is called only after task1 function executes successfully. The wrapper that will make use of these functions will have function definition.

---

`function task1(){
console.log('Inside task1');
}`

`function task2(){
console.log('Inside task2');
}`

`var functionArrayToBeUsed = readFromJson(functionArray);`

`\\functionArrayToBeUsed has all tasks that need to be finished`

---

What will be an ideal way to do this using Promises.

Comment: That data structure more-or-less forces you to use the dreaded `eval()`. Do you have the freedom to refactor everything?

Comment: Well, that data structure is a key for the wrapper, in terms of what all functions it has to execute. Changing that structure might not be feasible, other than that is fine.

Comment: Could you serve the JSON as `"functionArray" : ["task1", "task2", ... , "taskN"]`, sans-braquettes?

Comment: Yes, thats not a problem.

Comment: OK, that makes things much simpler - answer in preparation .....

Comment: So these task functions return promises?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the JSON to be served in the form ...

```
"functionArray" : ["task1", "task2", ... , "taskN"]
```

... and the tasks to be properties of a `tasks` object ...

```
var tasks = {
    task1: function () {
        console.log('Inside task1');
    },
    task2: function () {
        console.log('Inside task2');
    }
};
```

... then you can do as follows.

**Synchronous tasks**

```
var functionArray = readFromJson(functionArray);
functionArray.reduce(function(previousResult, taskName) {
    return tasks[taskname](previousResult);
}, null);
```

**Asynchronous (or mixed) tasks**

```
var functionArray = readFromJson(functionArray);
functionArray.reduce(function(p, taskName) {
    return p.then(tasks[taskname]);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

*In both cases, array method `.reduce()` provides a compact way to build a `.then()` chain, seeded with a resolved promise to get things started.*

These examples give you more than you asked for. In each approach, a result is passed through from each function to the next. If the functions don't accept any params, then this feature will do no harm.

That said, everything would need to be more defensively coded if any of the functions was likely to return `undefined`.

Comment: Doh! thanks BG, mind in neutral there on assimilation - edited. Bergi pointed out recently that we really need a canonical answer on `.reduce()`. I learned it [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) though it really deserves a more comprehensive treatment. I would write the canonical, but I'm not sure I'm the right person.

Comment: Thanks, much better now :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not tested):

```
function callSequentaly(promises) {
    var values = [];
    var newPromises = [];

    function makeSequence(prevPromise, nextPromise) {
        return prevPromise.then(function (value) {
            values.push(value);
            return nextPromise;
        });
    }

    newPromises.push(promises[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < promises.length; i++) {
        newPromises.push(makeSequence(newPromises[i - 1], promises[i]));
    }

    var defer = Promise.defer();

    Promise.all(newPromises)
        .then(function () { defer.resolve(values) })
        .catch(function (e) { defer.reject(e) });

    return defer.promise;
}
```